efficiently reverse EISH to HSIE
Reverse
****   *   ****   *  *
*      *   *      *  *
****   *   ****   ****
*      *      *   *  *
****   *   ****   *  *

to
*  *   ****   *   ****
*  *   *      *   *
****   ****   *   ****
*  *      *   *   *
*  *   ****   *   ****

by moving minimal amount of dots (being e.g. stars * here in ascii art representation).
For reference I add old hint again (which I probably should not have deleted ... sorry for that):

 reverse Coptic number 3 (šomt) has similar minimal solution


The puzzle asks to reverse EISH to HSIE by moving the minimal amount of dots, with some lateral thinking.
It is possible to reverse EISH to HSIE by moving one dot, which must be minimal.
Begin with EISH which is

 represented in Morse code as dots: . .. ... ....

Then move

 dot number 9 to the position after dot number 1:
 .... ... .. .

We now have

 HSIE, represented in Morse code.


Oh yeah typo... too much time on summer vac away from puzzles : )

...So we were supposed to ignore the majority of the question, including the clarification notes, focus on a small bit, and interpret it in a way directly contradicted by the parts we ignored?

@Deusovi : thanks for constructive comment. I have mentioned in comment for every previously given answer given that something 'extra' is needed apart from mathematics (nabgure ercerfragngvba). Adding [sequence] tag 1 2 3 4 was perhaps not so relevant.

I think this was a well designed lateral thinking puzzle. If it were just a matter of moving stars around optimally it wouldn't be very puzzling. And without the stars as a distraction it would have been too easy.

Your edit was probably just a mix-up of names, but it's interesting that Louis doesn't score so badly when it comes to moving dots.

I'll agree with others that I don't think this answers the question. The title says "reverse EISH TO HSIE*, but the question says to reverse [some ascii art] to [some other ascii art]. This answer answers the title, but not the question.

@TimC The question says that the letters were represented in ASCII art, but it ever actually says that the ASCII art itself was what needed to be reversed. It was intentionally misleading, but not directly contradictory.

Am I missing something about the solution? I don't understand how that operation lead from state #1 to state #2.

@Abion47 - The question doesn't actually mention letters at all. The terms "HSIE" and EISH" don't appear in the question outside of the title. The objects it tells us to reverse are only presented as ASCII art (which happens to look like letters). As for how this answer works: if the translation to Moorse Code is allowed, you can go from * ** *** **** to **** *** ** * by moving the second to the last star to fill the first space, splitting the final **** into ** * while combining the starting * ** into ****.

@TimC Ah I see, thank you. As for the question, that just makes it even more nebulous as any answer would be valid so long as it satisfies transforming object A to object B using the method of moving dots where object A and object B can be represented by the respective ASCII arts. Presented that way, it could be argued that there's an even more efficient answer where the terms "HSIE and EISH" are represented by 3D perspective art that shows either term based on where the observer is standing. In that answer, the solution is moving 0 dots and instead simply moving the position of the observer.

@Abion47 The question was nebulous, and, on purpose, to not make it easy. I am not familiar with enigmatic-puzzle lateral-thinking puzzles. So please bear with me in that I might have mislead people, something I hereby sincerely apologize for. The challenge was indeed to transform the terms to-from another representation which somehow would (like ascii art representation example) consist of building blocks that can be interpreted as movable dots. So now if you find such transformation and representation with less moves, please feel free to post your finding as answer, if you wish so.

@Amoz : thanks for kind reaction ...

@MOehm : I see the dots moving in your 'Louis' representation, but I must modestly admit I did not get to grasp the full essence. :-)

@FirstNameLastName: Perhaps if you knew Louis better? ;) His name was in the first draft of this answer. I find it interesting that the Braille representations of EISH and HSIE are also quite close.

@MOehm : OK! I see now. For sure: coincidence was not intentional. Nice catch.

@Abion47 & all : If one considers having a look from other side of table or paper, no dots need to be moved at all, but of course, one still needs an efficient representation.

@FirstNameLastName Not all of the letters involved are symmetrical in a way that would survive a mirrored/rotated transformation. As such, that approach would turn "EISH" to something resembling "H2I3", not "HSIE".

@Abion47  I meant: look at .... ... .. . from other side :-) no need to move dots

3:

 rotate
 


 move two dots of rightmost to left


nice mathematical answer but the question has an enigmatic challenge

At first view I knew it seems to me it is not so simple :-)

By rotating, you first moved all the dots (except possibly one).

@WeatherVane or perhaps moved to other side of the table and moved no dots :-) then total was 2

Working completely in-place,

 17 points are in different positions between the start and end.

If we don't,

 we can move the H (12 points) to the other side, then transform the S and E into each other by moving one point each, for a total of 14.


I count 45 points in the original figure, so I'm not sure what your point is. (With the "obvious" overlap I still end up with more than your total.)

nice mathematical answer but the question needs some 'out of the box' vision.

I've fixed the count, which was a silly oversight. I don't recall the [lateral-thinking] tag being present when writing my answer, although I don't know how to verify that.

The edit history has timestamps for all revisions of the question. The tags were edited nearly nine hours after you answered.


 If you start with 2 spaces between each 4-wide letter, you can move the source 3 spaces to the left.
 Then you swap according to this pattern:


 ---*  *  ****  *  *+++
 -  +  *  *     *  *
 ---*++*  ****  *--*+++
 -  +  *     *  *  *
 ---*  *  ****  *  *+++

This gives 13 dots moved.

I didn't understand the hint, and so didn't use the hint.

Welcome to Puzzle Exchange! I left 3 spaces in between letters and one letter (I) is not 4 but 1 space wide. That said, perhaps you look at a constructed variant?

I was trying to shift to align the letter verticals but I thought you might say something like the gaps were intentional.

not so much are gaps intentional but rather 13 dots is sub optimal, but then, please take into account the puzzle has some particular angle to look at. Again: welcome to PE!

Thanks, I was just caught by this interesting looking puzzle, I am clearly still missing some key to the optimisation, and horizontal shifting isn't it.

Check the latest edit to see how to properly spoiler preformatted text blocks.

I removed hint to keep puzzle hard.

@AxiomaticSystem : thanks for edit ! and to Heather : nice mathematical solution but there is some other ingredient needed.

Thanks for help with the formatting, I'll have another think about the other ingredient.
